# i keep getting uncaught syntaxError: cannot use import use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript

```
import Paddle from './paddle';


let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,600);

let paddle = new paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

Paddle.draw(ctx);
```

Comment: When used in browsers code that needs to export/import modules needs to be in a specific script tag that has it's type set to `module`, ie `<script type="module">`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @Patric Evans in the comment, you need to set the type of script to module inside the script tag:

`<script type="module" src="yourFile.js"></script>`